# setNavigationBarHidden with options

Tags: objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uianimation

Is there a way to adjust the duration and curve of the setNavigationBarHidden method of a UINavigationController? It appears far too quickly and does not mesh with the other animations on my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your own hide animation as follows:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}];
```